# Cakephp 3 erro RSS

Tags: controller, cakephp-3, rss

Quero fazer um gerador de RSS, segui o tutorial do mesmo em http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/rss.html. Porém as coisas não estão trabalhando como deveriam, pois de acordo com a documentação, quando eu acessar o route do item, com a extensão .rss, ele deveria retornar o RSS, no meu caso é o *controller posts*

```
/posts/index.rss
```

Mas quando eu tento isso, ele tenta encontrar uma controller, e me retorna o erro de controller não encontrado

```
The action index.rss is not defined in PostsController
```

Obs: Declarei o `Router::extensions('rss');`
     também contém `::initialize()` com `loadComponent('RequestHandler');`

Sabe o erro? Tem algum exemplo prático?

Comment: Posta o código que fizestes. Criastes alguma rota manual?

Comment: o problema foi resolvido [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802889/cakephp-3-rss-error) ... Obrigado pela ajuda